# Send image to Pebble from iOS

Tags: ios, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I was hoping to send an image to pebble from iOS, through AppMessage. I've seen apps which, for instance, send an image from the camera on the phone, to the pebble.

But on the documentation, it says

> "The maximum buffer size for AppMessage is currently 124 bytes."

So this must be possible, but i can't figure out how to send an image across.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
title

    The custom title (max. 20 bytes of UTF-8 string)

icon

    The custom icon (max. 32x32 pixels, black/white only)
```